# Bash Command Substitution fail

Tags: linux, bash, command-substitution

I need some Specs and Data from Number of Latops in a ini-file. 
When I try to get the IP-Adress with `ip addr list <interface>` nothing happens in the script. Not even a Error.

I try to quote stuff in my code. Nothing change.

```
for w2 in /sys/class/net/wl* 
    do 
        w2i=$(basename $w2)
        echo $w2i
        addr=$(ip -o -4 addr list $w2i | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
        echo $addr
        echo -e "$w2i=$addr"
done
```

I Think maybe it is because of the Varibales but this fails also (interface is set 'manually'):

```
for w2 in /sys/class/net/wl* 
    do 
        w2i=$(basename $w2)
        echo $w2i
        addr=$(ip -o -4 addr list wlp3s0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
        echo $addr
        echo -e "$w2i=$addr"
done
```

When i run the script i get `wlp3s0` and i must close the script with ctl-c. When i run `ip -o -4 addr list wlp3s0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1` it gives me my ip like i expected.

**EDIT**

I just need to wirte the full-path of the `ip`-command. Can somebody explain why i have to do this? And especially it is not necessary for `cut` or `awk` that also based in `/usr/bin/`?

```
for w2 in /sys/class/net/wl* 
    do 
        w2i=$(basename $w2)
        echo $w2i
        addr=$(/usr/bin/ip -o -4 addr list "$w2i" | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
        echo $addr
        echo -e "$w2i=$addr"
done
}
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Check content of `$PATH` in your script.

Comment: Do you have `ip` defined as a function or something in the script? Try putting `type ip` in the script to see what it thinks `ip` means in that context.

Comment: @GordonDavisson 
thank you! yes, ip was a function a few lines before in the script. 
I forgot it because I wrote that many days ago. and obviously I am blind.